# Centralizers in C*-algebra

Tags: c-star-algebras, fa.functional-analysis, von-neumann-algebras

Let $a,b\in A$ be self-adjoint elements in $C^*$-algebra $A$ with equal centralizers, $\{x\in A; [a,x]=0\}=\{x\in A; [b,x]=0\}$. Can we say anything about the correspondence between $a$ and $b$?

For example, if $A=B(H)$ for a separable Hilbert space $H$, then according to the double commutant theorem $b=f(a)$ for some Borel function $f$ on the spectrum of $a$.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: are you assuming $a$ is normal? (Otherwise take $a$ to be quasinilpotent.)

Comment: Certainly your condition implies that $a$ lies in the double commutant of $b$, and that $b$ lies in the double commutant of $a$, but off the top of my head I don't see how to say more without using some assumptions such as normality.

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that a and b are self-adjoint. Sorry for the mistake and thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: What type of general statement are you looking for?  Have you considered the case when $A$ is commutative?

Comment: Since the condition trivially holds if A is commutative, we exclude that case. In the noncommutative case, does it hold the same correspondence as in $B(H)$?

Comment: @spelas: if that is the particular question you are interested in, why don't you edit the question? Moreover, if you have a *particular* class of noncommutative $C^\ast$ algebras in mind, you should specify which ones you mean. (Note that if $A$ is a von Neumann algebra then everything works as in $B(H)$.)

Comment: @Spelas: Since you want to apply Borel functional calculus this is really a question about von Neumann algebras rather than $C^*$-algebras.  It might be more insightful to edit the question to ask which von Neumann algebras $N$ have the property that for all commutative von Neumann subalgebras $A, B \subset N$ we have $A' \cap N = B' \cap N \implies A = B$.

Comment: @Yemon: This doesn't work for all von Neumann algebras.  For instance if $\mathbb F_2 = \langle a, b \rangle$ is the free group, $A = \{ a \}''$, $B = \{ a^2 \}''$.  Then it is known that $A' \cap L\mathbb F_2 = B' \cap L\mathbb F_2$.  In fact, my first guess would be that this property actually characterizes $B(H)$.

Comment: I am interested in the situation of general $C^*$-algebras, and some "nontrivial" correspondence between $a$ and $b$. Since the correspondence in $B(H)$ is quite "strong", I expected that something nonobvious can be said also in general $C^*$-algebras.

Comment: @Spelas:  Since you are interested in properties for general $C^*$-algebras I'll ask the von Neumann algebra question in a separate post.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85092/relative-commutants-of-abelian-von-neumann-algebras

Answer (score 6):

The condition 
`\begin{equation}
\{x\in A: [a,x]=0\}=\{x\in A: [b,x]=0\}
\end{equation}`
implies that $a$ and $b$ commute.

*(Edit: after spelas noted that there was a relation in the example I wrote, now I'm rewriting the answer with an example where there is no relation)*

This is of course no characterization, as 
Jesse's example above shows. But I don't think much can be said in this generality: consider $A=L^\infty[0,1]\oplus \ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$, $a=f\oplus 0_m$, $b=0_n\oplus g$, where $f,g$ are respectively the functions $f(t)=t$, $g(n)=1/n$. Then $\{a\}'\cap A=A$, $\{b\}'\cap A=A$. So for this $a,b$ we have the equality among the centralizers, but no "correspondence" (in the language of the original question) between the two elements; indeed, $W^*(b)=\mathbb{C}\,1\oplus\ell^\infty(\mathbb{N})$, $W^*(a)=L^\infty[0,1]\oplus\mathbb{C}\,1$.

There's nothing very particular about this example, any two selfadjoint elements in the centre of a C$^*$-algebra $A$ will do.

Comment: But it holds a+b=1, so b=f(a).

Comment: *(sorry I saw your comment several weeks later)*

True, but as I said, "any two selfadjoint elements in the centre of a C$^*$-algebra will do". If you want, I'll edit the answer to show an example where no relation exists.